# Laravel Homestead setup but does not sync hidden files

Tags: homestead

Hi I've setup Homestead correctly but when I ssh into my Vagrant instance I can see all my files just not the hidden ones (.env, .git, .gitignore are missing). I'm trying to run webpack-dev-server within my instance and it needs my .env file to run. Is it normal that hidden files are not synced?

My .yaml file:
[image]

Comment: Hidden files don't show when using the `ls` command (which I guess is what u're doing). They are still there, however. You can try something like `nano .env` and you'll see that you can edit your env from the console.

Comment: Ah gotcha. May be you could add this as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden files don't show when using the `ls` command (which I guess is what u're doing). They are still there, however. You can try something like `nano .env` and you'll see that you can edit your env from the console :)

Another command you could use is `ls -a`, which should show all files regardless of whether they're hidden or not.